# Is it possible to return to a CSS media query declaration from Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a DIV where I adjust the font size in CSS depending on the viewport size:

```
font-size:1em;
@media only screen and (min-width: 300px) {
    font-size:2em; 
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    font-size:3em; 
}
```

However, I also have Javascript that changes the font size depending on whether or not the user scrolls down.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1) {
        $('#div').css('font-size', '1em');       
    }
    else {
        $('#div').css('font-size', '3em');
    }
});
```

The problem is, after the user has scrolled down and up again at least once, the Javascript has set the `font-size` to `3em`, and the `@media` declarations no longer apply.

Is it possible to make it so that in the Javascript `else` clause, the style reverts back to what is declared in the CSS and `@media` conditions?

Comment: Use `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()` methods instead of using `.css()` method which applies inline styles which has highest precedence..

Comment: @Mr.Alien I think you should answer this question. IMO that's the best advice.

Comment: @Danield Cool, thanks, I'll do the needful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting the font-size back to normal with javascript you could set it to 'nothing'. That way the styles defined in your css get applied.

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1) {
        $('#div').css('font-size', '1em');       
    }
    else {
        $('#div').css('font-size', '');
    }
});
```

Comment: Although there were two answers with the same information, I gave this one the check just for having more complete code.

Answer (score 3):

As I already commented, instead of using `.css()` which defines inline styles for an element has highest precedence hence you can reset it with nothing but jQuery again which is dirty or might get dirty if you have more than couple of properties to reset/change in `if` `else`.

So instead of using <s>`.css()`</s> you should be using `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()` methods and will accomplish well of what you are looking for.

Comment: Upvoted because this is very useful information, and in some situations would definitely be the way to go. However, in my case I had some DIVs with styles applied via their id, and the styles specified classes would not over ride them. So, in this instance in particular, the other answer I marked correct made my life a little easier.

Answer (score 1):

The style you apply to `#div` overrides the `@media` declaration so you have to remove the applied style. Use an empty style (i.e. `$('#div').css('font-size', '')` ) to remove a css property.